# Good GUI and UI-Designer Extension with Drag and Drop for VS2012

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I'm programmed a algorithm. Now I'm looking for a good and simple designer, where I can integrate my sourcecode. My Source is written in C/C++ including WinAPI for Bluetooth-Devices.

I tried C++/CLR .NET with winforms but it's not so well. Someone tolds me that I should use MFC in VS 2012 but it's not a elegant way.

QT5Creator is also not possible: I think my code is not compatible with it.

Do you have any experience with any extensions for VS2012?

Thanks

Comment: nobody here or have a clue?

Comment: There is no good GUI designer for pure WinAPI from what I can tell.